# How to pad 1em in a layout?

Tags: android, layout

In my Android app, I have two `TextView`s next to eachother, which I want to separate [1em](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29), to create two words that are separated by a space.

`android:paddingLeft` though, doesn't support `1em` as a value:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/wordone"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvLabel"
    android:paddingLeft="1em"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/wordtwo"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

How can I do this reliably and portably?

Comment: if the text isn't going to change you can set `android:ems="<chars in your string+1>"`
Edit: I am not sure how ems works but it might not be consistant with all text sizes